# Automation: Extract links from xml Menu

Tags: selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, automation

Hi I wonder if anybody can help me on something that has been puzzling me.

I am trying to extract all the child links from the menu on page:

http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml#/cat/1215135760597

I have tried using selenium and searching for xpath but it seems that the link for the lowest child items only appears when you are only one level above and to go through each variant there are over 2000 possibilities. Not only would I like a way of saving time but also a method that would allow nothing to be missed out by tired right-click-save link location and paste into textfile error!

The lowest child links looks like: http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml#/shelf/910001112609/1/so_false

This link is for Bananas (which is a apt description of where I am at the moment!)

where there is the word `shelf` in them. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide an output file sample. Few lines will be enough.

Comment: Hi Andrey,I would like the output file to looks like this: http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215259254410/1/so_false
http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/910000976333/1/so_false
http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/910000975878/1/so_false
http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215312754908/1/so_false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's really not trivial task, but has solution. Below C# test sample which walk through all links on your site and retrieve href text from menus which has not children (last in the lists). Port to your language yourself =)

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

[TestFixture]
public class WalkLink
{
    private ChromeDriver driver;
    private const string url = @"http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml";

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = CreateBrowser(url);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Dispose();
    }

    [Test]
    public void WalkingThrough()
    {
        const string rootItemsSelector = "#primary-nav-items > li > div > div > div > ul > div > li";
        Console.WriteLine("We are here");

        var navItems = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#primary-nav-items > li"));
        var menusCount = navItems.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < menusCount; i++)
        {
            navItems[i].Click();
            Walk(rootItemsSelector);
        }
    }

    void Walk(string selector)
    {
        var items = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(selector));
        var count = items.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++)
            {
                try
                {
                    items = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(selector));
                    Assert.AreEqual(count, items.Count);
                    var item = items[i];
                    item.Click();
                    if (!HasChild(item))
                    {
                        //HERE you can save href to your file
                        Console.WriteLine(Href(item));
                    }

                    break;
                }
                catch{}
            }

            Walk(selector + " > ul > div > li");
        }
    }

    public bool HasChild(IWebElement element)
    {
        var link = element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a"));
        return link.GetAttribute("class").Contains("hasChild");
    }

    public string Href(IWebElement element)
    {
        var link = element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a"));
        return link.GetAttribute("href");
    }

    internal static ChromeDriver CreateBrowser(string urlString)
    {
        var url = new Uri(urlString);
        ChromeDriver browser = null;
        browser = new ChromeDriver();
        browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        return browser;
    }
}
```